# How to calculate execution time in DXL

Tags: performance, time, execution-time, requirements, ibm-doors

I'm trying to make a program in DXL (IBM DOORS) and I have a doubt. I have several ideas about how to make the script, but I would like to know which one has the least cost in time.

For example (this isn't the real program that I want to do, but a triviality to exemplify what I ask), in the program below how can I know the time it takes me in seconds?

```
Folder f = current Folder;

void ScanFolder(Folder f) {

    Item itm;

    for itm in f do {

        if (type(itm) == "Folder") {

            print "FOLDER: " fullName(itm) "\n";
            ScanFolder(folder(itm));

        }

        else if (type(itm) == "Formal") {

            print "MODULE: " fullName(itm) "\n";

        }

        else {

            ;

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If seconds is detailed enough, you can use `intOf (today())` as start and end time. In case you need millisecods, there's an undocumented perm `int getTickCount_ ()`